# Lightning Effects in LibGdx

Tags: opengl, animation, libgdx

In my LibGdx based android game, I wish to create a lightning effect. I do not find any tutorial for that except the below  one.
http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/libgdx-lightning-effect-code/35553/msg/336904/view.html#msg336904

This document is not clear in explaining the steps to achieve the Lightning effect.

Question

1. If you have idea about the above mentioned library. Please let me know how to use it.
2. If you have any other library for creating the lightning effect please let me know

Comment: What about libgdx Particles?

Comment: LibGdx  Particles supported in Android ?

Answer (score 0):

What I did for [my game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buckriderstudio.bounceandbreak.android) (you can see the effect when you get the blue lightning ball) is having a couple of different lightning bolt images. I know the center/start of the bolt and on that point I rotate and stretch the bolt towards a target. I start drawing the bolt full opacity and quickly make it transparent. To enhance the effect even more you can do a couple of bolts quickly after eachother and add flashes to your scene.

Other options are to go with shaders, but I cannot help you with that.